# orgmode - change code block background color

Tags: org-mode

Below code will change html export background color to #eff0fe:

```
#+ATTR_HTML: :style background-color:#eff0fe;
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
hello world!
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

like below:
[image]

How can we change the background color when edit in emacs?

I saw [Pretty fontification of source code blocks](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/examples/fontify-src-code-blocks.html) document but sounds like it doesn't work for me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like some face name changed, below config works:

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(org-block-begin-line
   ((t (:underline "#A7A6AA" :foreground "#008ED1" :background "#EAEAFF" :extend t))))
 '(org-block
   ((t (:background "#EFF0F1" :extend t))))
 '(org-block-end-line
   ((t (:overline "#A7A6AA" :foreground "#008ED1" :background "#EAEAFF" :extend t))))
 )
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 12):

Another approach (which I think is more general) is explained in [this page](https://orgmode.org/manual/Editing-source-code.html) and I have copy-pasted the snippet here. It will only change the code block, and not the `#+BEGIN`, `#+END`, or `#+RESULTS` lines.

The example below will darken the code block by 3 percent (notice the number 3 at the last parameter) relative to the background color of your emacs theme. However, if you change your theme during editing the color of the code block will stay the same.

```
(require 'color)
(set-face-attribute 'org-block nil :background
                    (color-darken-name
                     (face-attribute 'default :background) 3))
```

Output using a light theme:

[image: light]

Output using a dark theme:

[image: dark]

You can modify further the code block color for individual programming language. The example below will modify the code block color for emacs-lisp and python.

```
(setq org-src-block-faces '(("emacs-lisp" (:background "#EEE2FF"))
                            ("python" (:background "#E5FFB8"))))
```

Comment: Either the URL is inaccurate or it has been changed. The correct URL is https://orgmode.org/manual/Editing-Source-Code.html